# How to maximize $\sum_i^n 1/2^{v_i}$

Tags: optimization

How to maximize $\sum_i^n\dfrac{1}{2^{v_i}}$ where $, v_i\in \mathbb{N}$, $0\leq v_i<k$ and $\sum_i^n\dfrac{1}{2^{v_i}}\leq 1$?. Could you give an idea to start to find an equivalent problem only using integer constraints?

Consider $n,k$ constants

Comment: What are you optimizing on? $n$, $k$, or $v$?

Comment: @nejimban on v. $k$ and $n$ are constants

Comment: Then I think $v_1=v_2=\ldots=v_n=1$ give the maximum.

Comment: @nejimban in this case the constraint $\sum_i2^{-v_i}\leq1$ is not satisfied for $n>2$.

Comment: @leoli Indeed, I missed that… What about $v_i=i$ if $1\le i<k$, and $v_i=0$ otherwise?